# Highcharts - x axis incorrect date labels appearing

Tags: jquery, highcharts

I've been creating a timeline with highcharts. Everything has been fine so far except a problem with the date labels on the x axis displaying incorrectly.

I have been over the code again and again and I cant seem to find the issue here.

I have created a demonstration of the issue [here (jsFiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/vJhfC/)

I was wondering if it's something to do with the way I'm defining dates:

```
Date.UTC(2013,04,30,01,00,00)
```

I really cant explain what is happening, the dates that go in, are not the dates that are displayed on the graph.

Any help would be fantastic, because I'm out of ideas!

Comment: But datalabels you mean lables on xAxis or datalabels above points?

Comment: Sorry if it was unclear I meant labels on x axis. If you notice, the data is all dated between 29th April and 1st may. Yet the graph displays 30th May on the x axis.

Comment: It related with fact, that in Date.UTC you should use 3 as index of months, instead of 4, because months are indexed from 0, not 1.

Comment: Thanks, all sorted! I'll add this as an answer.

Comment: Ok great, you can mark this post as answer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [Sebastian Bochan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2021935/sebastian-bochan) - "It related with fact, that in Date.UTC you should
>   use 3 as index of months, instead of 4, because months are indexed
>   from 0, not 1."

Cheers for the answer!